# Ubuntu-Server: Every SSH-Connect creates non deleted cgroup

Tags: git, ubuntu, docker, ssh, ubuntu-14.04

We are running some *Ubuntu* 14.04 servers that somehow create a new *cgroup* for each SSH-session created, but sadly the cgroups do not get deleted when the session is closed.

As we are also running *GitLab* on one of those servers and some Git-clients poll once per minute we end up with thousands of zombie cgroups for the git-user per week.

About once per month we reach the `cgroup-limit` leading to problems with docker saying:

> starting container process caused "process_linux.go:258: applying
>   cgroup configuration for process caused \"mkdir
>   /sys/fs/cgroup/memory/docker/28485427c2689d7a2c4be83990af873e9ab5732c5c741f0d10bfc3ba21b1d167:
>   no space left on device\""

It seems that the problem only occurs on servers having docker installed. The other servers delete the cgroups correctly. Maybe one of dockers install-dependencies is the problem here.
Docker itself is deleting its cgroups correctly.

The only fix for the problem we know of, is restarting the machine.

Here the output of `docker version`:

```
Client:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:10:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64

Server:
 Version:      17.03.1-ce
 API version:  1.27 (minimum version 1.12)
 Go version:   go1.7.5
 Git commit:   c6d412e
 Built:        Mon Mar 27 17:10:36 2017
 OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
 Experimental: false
```

Here the output of `docker info`

```
Containers: 3
 Running: 3
 Paused: 0
 Stopped: 0
Images: 4576
Server Version: 17.03.1-ce
Storage Driver: aufs
 Root Dir: /var/lib/docker/aufs
 Backing Filesystem: extfs
 Dirs: 2359
 Dirperm1 Supported: true
Logging Driver: json-file
Cgroup Driver: cgroupfs
Plugins: 
 Volume: local
 Network: bridge host macvlan null overlay
Swarm: inactive
Runtimes: runc
Default Runtime: runc
Init Binary: docker-init
containerd version: 4ab9917febca54791c5f071a9d1f404867857fcc
runc version: 54296cf40ad8143b62dbcaa1d90e520a2136ddfe
init version: 949e6fa
Security Options:
 apparmor
Kernel Version: 4.2.0-42-generic
Operating System: Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
OSType: linux
Architecture: x86_64
CPUs: 8
Total Memory: 31.33 GiB
Name: repo
ID: KT6V:FLPI:EHY6:2FSP:NEBT:T65W:23IX:IRFK:AQM5:KSLM:FQ3D:57X5
Docker Root Dir: /var/lib/docker
Debug Mode (client): false
Debug Mode (server): false
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
WARNING: No swap limit support
Experimental: false
Insecure Registries:
 127.0.0.0/8
Live Restore Enabled: false
```

The kernel version via `uname -a`:

> Linux repo 4.2.0-42-generic #49~14.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jun 29 20:22:11 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

`cat /proc/cgroups` after ~3h uptime:

```
#subsys_name    hierarchy   num_cgroups enabled
cpuset  1   623 1
cpu 2   627 1
cpuacct 3   623 1
blkio   4   623 1
memory  5   627 1
devices 6   623 1
freezer 7   623 1
net_cls 8   623 1
perf_event  9   623 1
net_prio    10  623 1
hugetlb 11  623 1
```

Of these 623 cgroups 616 are in `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory/user/998.user` where user 998 is the git user.

Comment: Paste the output logs of `docker info` and `docker version`. Also what version of the Kernel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know it is not the ideal solution as it only removes the symptom and not the cause, but for now I created a script that can be run via cron.

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
CGROUP_BASE_DIR="/sys/fs/cgroup"
declare -a CGROUP_SUBSYSTEMS=('cpuset' 'cpu' 'cpuacct' 'blkio' 'memory' 'devices' 'freezer' 'net_cls' 'perf_event' 'net_prio' 'hugetlb')

for CGROUP_SUBSYSTEM in "${CGROUP_SUBSYSTEMS[@]}"; do
        cd "${CGROUP_BASE_DIR}/${CGROUP_SUBSYSTEM}"
        for OLD_CGROUP in $(find user/*.user/*.session -type d -ctime +10); do
                /usr/bin/cgdelete -r "${CGROUP_SUBSYSTEM}:/${OLD_CGROUP}"
        done
done
```

This will search all session-cgroups older than 10 days and deletes them using `cgdelete` from `cgroup-tools`.